# DirectX Delete All Objects

Tags: c#, directx, sharpdx

My application uses Disposing of (I hope) all objects I create.
However, If I restart the part of my application that uses Direct3D and all the objects based on the device object my memory grows a lot and fast.

If I close this part of the application I call Dispose on everything and the last object I dispose is the device.

Is there a way to ensure to dispose all in that case? I want all to be clean or deleted. Recreating a new device is no problem. I just want to have a clean memory state. But I seem to have a leak.

If I debug it with SharpDX.Diagnostics.ObjectTracker.FindActiveObjects() I get Count = 0.

Are there any other useful tools I can use? Or commands that achieve what I want? Maybe I am missing disposes somewhere still, not saying it couldn't. But is there a way to dispose and flush everything at once?

Thanks in advance

Comment: My experience is that graphics drivers allocate memory and dispose it independently of the Direct3D objects you have allocated. How much they do so varies by driver vendor, but if you create and destroy a lot of objects quickly you can end up with out-of-memory exceptions coming from Direct3D.

Comment: Thank you, actually I found a way for this issue to track down some hidden leaks in my logic by checking all active objects and references. By fixing all the warnings in my output and disposing everything that showed remainding references I think I have no object leaks anymore. However, that lead me to my newer question. What you say I can confirm, I have a test app that does that quickly and runs in the kind of error you mentioned.